# nodejs Net socket client communication with c# .net server application

Tags: c#, node.js, sockets, .net-core

I have a C# .net server service application which listens on port 11111 for a connection. I have tested it with another c# test application which can send and recieve communication for and from the server.

Now the production scenario is that this C# .net server application is to recieve connection from, amongst others, a nodejs client which is encapsulated in Electron. So i create this function in NodeJS

```
const net = require( "net");
const socket = new net.Socket();
socket.connect('11111','127.0.0.1');
exports.socket = socket;
```

I import it in the IPC layer of Electron.

const { socket } = require("./socketInit.js");

and when doing that i get this error

A JavaScript error occurred in the browser process
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:11111
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16)

It wont connect to the server socket.

Im not even using the socket yet, but i understand that the connection attempt is doing the handshake and that must be where the error happens.

Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong ?

TY for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Im quite sure it is because the code is in a renderpass which runs several times, and then the code in reality tries to open a connection on a port where a connection is already open each time there is a renderpass except from the first.

I destroyed the connection after sending and now i dont get the error anymore. But im not getting any data send to the server, but that is for another question.

I'm integrating this into an existing codebase, which i don't fully understand as im a total newb to NodeJS, Javascript and Electron, so im not sure how it all works :)